# Solutions to critically damped harmonic oscillator?

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, oscillators, differential-equations, dissipation

From MITOpenCourseWare, I was learning about the damped harmonic oscillator. Some context is pasted below.

> Case (iii) Critical Damping (repeated real roots)
>
> If $b^2 = 4mk$ then the term under the square root is 0 and the characteristic polynomial has repeated roots, $−b/2m, −b/2m$.
>
> Now we use the roots to solve equation (1) in this case. We have only one exponential solution, so we need to multiply it by $t$ to get the second solution.
> Basic solutions: $e^{-bt/2m},~te^{-bt/2m}$.

What I don't understand is how we gathered the part "we need to multiply it by $t$ to get the second solution". I understand that we need two solutions, and the polynomial only provides one, but how did we obtain the fact that "multiple by $t$" is the way to get two solutions.

Comment: *Now we use the roots to solve equation (1) in this case.* You didn’t give equation (1).

Comment: Equation (1) was the equation for a damped harmonic oscillator.

Comment: *how did we obtain the fact that "multiple by t" is the way to get two solutions?* [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus)#Repeated_real_roots) explains what the “other” solutions are when the characteristic polynomial of the differential equation has repeated real roots. Did the MIT course not cover that? If it didn’t, maybe it was covered in a course on differential equations that was a prerequisite?

Comment: Link to MITOpenCourseWare page?

Comment: explained here: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/de/repeatedroots.aspx

Comment: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/7e212064ad281d00e1dac893b1f722a7_MIT18_03SCF11_s13_2text.pdf.

Comment: Everything is simpler now that I understand that it is called repeated roots and can find materials online. Though I am now seeing how much math is skipped in my physics course where I am just told to accept as truth.